# Map cnames to subdomain apache (directadmin)

Tags: bash, apache, directadmin

I want to create the following setup:

1. User visits my.domain.com
2. A specific subdomain will be loaded via CNAME (i.e. my.maindomain.com)

How can I achieve this using apache / directadmin (custom build 2)? I have full control over the webserver (mydomain.com) and some programming skills, but can't really write bash or python or so.

I have domain.com set up with a CNAME record ('my' > my.maindomain.com.), but (ofcourse) now I see the 'Apache is functioning normally' page.

TLDR: The subdomain 'my.maindomain.com' already works, so in short I'm looking for a way to dynamically map my.domain.com to my.maindomain.com using apache on directadmin (CB2).

NB: A validation isn't really required in this process, I will validate the referring domain (my.domain.com) on maindomain.com.

Any advice is welcome, thanks in advance and have a great weekend.